# Multiple Inserts in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I tried to do below insert in SQL Developer

```
 insert into tabletest values 
(1, null, 23, 2020),
(2, null, 23, 2021),
(3, 77, 23, 2022),
(4, 77, 23, 2023),
(5, 77, 23, 2024),
(6, null, 23, 2025);
```

But it's giving me below error

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"

Can someone tell me what's the error in the query please

Comment: OracleDB does not allow multiple values blocks in INSERT .. VALUES. Use INSERT .. SELECT instead.

Comment: This command is allowed on SQL Server but not on Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multiple inserts in the Oracle database, you can use one of these solutions

```sql
insert all 
 into tabletest values (1, null, 23, 2020)
 into tabletest values (2, null, 23, 2021)
 into tabletest values (3, 77, 23, 2022)
 into tabletest values (4, 77, 23, 2023)
 into tabletest values (5, 77, 23, 2024)
 into tabletest values (6, null, 23, 2025)
 select * from dual
 ;
```

or

```sql
insert into tabletest
    select 1, null, 23, 2020 from dual union all
    select 2, null, 23, 2021 from dual union all
    select 3, 77, 23, 2022 from dual union all
    select 4, 77, 23, 2023 from dual union all
    select 5, 77, 23, 2024 from dual union all
    select 6, null, 23, 2025 from dual
;
```

Comment: Or simply 6 different INSERT with values.